# How set file path within the php class

Tags: php

this is my php project dir structure

```
My_Project
  ->cache
  ->config
  ->lib
 TestClass.php
```

my `TestClass.php` contains method `cacheSet()`, it creates file within the `cache/` dir. so my question is how I set path to `CACHE_DIR` within that method.

```
class TestClass{

.....

public function cacheSet($filename, $data)
{

    $filename = CACHE_DIR . '/' . $filename. '.cache';
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($file, serialize($data));
    fclose($file);
}

}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a class, you would most likely do this:

```
public function cacheSet($filename, $data){
    $this->filename = CACHE_DIR . '/' . $filename. '.cache';
    $this->file = fopen($this->filename, 'w');
    fwrite($this->file, serialize($data));
    fclose($this->file);
}
```

I am not 100% sure of this, but if it's in a class, then it would most likely be this. Then at the start of your class, before you do the class TestClass{ you would want to do something like $class = new TestClass();

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
class TestClass{

.....
const CACHE_DIR = "your dir";

public function cacheSet($filename, $data)
{

    $filename = CACHE_DIR . '/' . $filename. '.cache';
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($file, serialize($data));
    fclose($file);
}

}
```

So you use [`const`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)